# What are SQL stored procedures, and why would I want to use them?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've seen articles that refer to "SQL stored procedures". What does this term mean, and what is their purpose when developing with SQL?

Comment: Google is your friend. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: This is an absolutely horrible question.  A simple search clearly states the definition and usage of Stored Procedures.

Comment: Maybe the person did some research, and didn't understand the concept (making it hard to ask a more specific question)

Comment: Good question, it's what I asked myself 10 years ago when I started SQL Server.  Close reason "not a real question" seems a bit arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged your question with MySQL, so

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html

> Stored routines (procedures and functions) are supported in MySQL 5.0.
>   A stored routine is a set of SQL statements that can be stored in the
>   server. Once this has been done, clients don't need to keep reissuing
>   the individual statements but can refer to the stored routine instead.

Answer (score 1):

In the absolute simplest terms, Stored Procedures are simply SQL statements that are stored in the database.

Since your question didn't ask for the benefits, or why you'd use stored procedures, I'll just mention that there are several benefits to using them, and that they're worth learning more about.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://booleandreams.wordpress.com/2008/03/24/why-to-use-stored-procedure-or-prepared-statement/) talks about the difference between prepared statements and stored procedures. I only bring this up because there can be some confusion between the two and it will help describe what a stored procedure is.